# Clearing the rest of the line while printing from Go program in Linux/macOS terminal and using carriage return

Tags: go, newline, carriage-return

If I create a loop in Go like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for i := 10; i >= 0; i-- {
        fmt.Printf("Time out in %d seconds\r", i)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

and run the program in Linux or macOS terminal, I will see the line printed in the first iteration correctly (`Time out in 10 seconds`) but in the next iteration (and every other in this case), since the string to print is one character shorter, I will see the leftovers from previous iteration as an additional `s` character in the end - `Time out in 9 secondss`, `Time out in 8 secondss`, etc.

Is there a simple way to clear printed line from previous iteration before printing out next line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To specify the width of an integer, use a number after the `%` in the verb. By default, the result will be right-justified and padded with spaces.

Use `%2d` instead of `%d`. It will fix your problem.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for i := 10; i >= 0; i-- {
        fmt.Printf("Time out in %2d seconds\r", i)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

- [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0vvJQQZndeI)

**Update**:

You can also execute `printf '\33c\e[3J'` command from your go code to clean up the terminal.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

var clearScreen = func() {
    cmd := exec.Command(`printf '\33c\e[3J'`) // clears the scrollback buffer as well as the screen.
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Run()
}

func main() {
    for i := 10; i >= 0; i-- {
        fmt.Printf("Time out in %2d seconds\r", i)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        clearScreen()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to play around with adding a number after `%` and also with left and right alignment and other things, but my OCD is not happy with anything I came up with :( This is a very simple example which can be solved also by adding simple space in the end, before `\r`, but in some more "complex" situation, there can be lots of garbage from previous iterations so I'd need something to avoid such cases too...

Comment: Perfect! I had to use a bit different syntax tho - `cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", \`printf '\33[K'\`)` and for my case, using only "clear line from cursor right" escape command (`\33[K`) was perfectly enough!